# Where, on my Ubuntu 14.04 system can I find and operate my newly installed RabbitVCS?

Tags: 14.04, search, rabbitvcs

I have installed RabbitVCS on Ubuntu 14.04. Where on my system can I find and operate it? 
I have installed it using PPA and also installed its packages i.e. CLI, CORE, Nautilus 3.

Now I want to know where to find the installed VCS and how to start it. Please, guide me!

Comment: Don't it work by opening the launcher and write rabbit ?

Comment: No i can't find it in launcher and rabbit shows no related package

Comment: OKay .. I googled it for you. This (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitvcs/B3R9r6S45j8) say that it should be in you right-click menu when you manage files.

Comment: Tried this `rabbitvcs commit` ?

Comment: I will add it as an answer then ..

Answer (score 1):

The functions of RabbitVCS is 'hidden' in the menu, when right-clicking on a file you want to manage.